# After storing data to my mongo db server and navigating to other component or alert i'm getting invalid hook error. Error and my code is given below

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Error i am getting is

```
"Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:26257:13)
    at Object.useContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43672:25)
    at useInRouterContext (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:39927:45)
    at Navigate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40760:4)
    at saveData (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1238:65)"
```

My code is :

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function SignUp(props) {
  const [user,setUser] = useState({
    name:"",email:"",password:""
  })

  let name, value;

  const handleInputs = (e) =>{
    console.log(e)
    name = e.target.name
    value = e.target.value

    setUser({...user, [name]:value})
  }
  const saveData =async (e) =>{
     e.preventDefault()

     const {name, email, password} = user

    const res = await fetch("/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type":"application/json"
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({
      name, email, password
      })
    })

    const data = await res.json()

    if (data.status === 422 || !data){
      window.alert("Invalid Registration");
      console.log("Invalid Registration")
    } else{
      window.alert("Registration Successfull");
      console.log("Registration Successfull")

      Navigate("/SignIn")
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container-field">
        <h1>Welcome to Notes Taking App</h1>
        <div className="col-md-5 m-auto">
          <div className="mt-3">
            <div className="card text-left">
              <div className="card-body">
                <h1 className="d-flex justify-content-center">Sign Up</h1>
                <form method="POST">
                  <label for="inputEmail4">Name</label>
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="col">
                      <input
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        class="form-control"
                        value={user.name}
                        onChange={handleInputs} 
                        placeholder="Enter your name"
                      />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="form-group col">
                        <label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
                        <input
                          type="email"
                          name="email"
                          class="form-control"
                          id="inputEmail4"
                          value={user.email}
                          onChange={handleInputs}
                          placeholder="Email"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputPassword4">Password</label>
                        <input
                          type="password"
                          name="password"
                          class="form-control"
                          id="inputPassword4"
                          value={user.password}
                          onChange={handleInputs}
                          placeholder="Password"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="d-grid gap-2 p-3">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onClick={saveData}>
                      Sign Up
                    </button>
                    <p className="m-auto">
                      Already have an account ?{" "}
                      <a href="/" onClick={props.switch}>
                        {" "}
                        Sign In
                      </a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: *"After [...] navigating to other component..."* - Is the code you're showing us the component you're navigating **from** or **to**?  Where specifically is this error happening?

Answer (score 1):

`Navigate` is a component, but you use as a function

I guess that you wanted to use `useNavigate`

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
```

```
export default function SignUp(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  ...
}
```

```
navigate("/SignIn")
```